# subprocess not working properly for this sudo /etc/init.d/windscribe-cli start

Tags: python, subprocess, sudo

Running without any error. But not starting the process... :(

```
    windscribe = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "<my pc password>", "|", "sudo", "/etc/init.d/windscribe-cli", "start"], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Per default `sudo` doesn't read from stdin, but from the terminal-device. So your echo sends it output into a pipe that is never read, while the `sudo` waits for output from the tty, which doesn't receive any input. Use

```
sudo -S
```

or

```
sudo --stdin
```

to read from stdin.